# Chart.js 2.0: How to dispplay tooltip while Mouse flyover

Tags: chart.js

I have a problem with the display of the tooltips when hovering over a mouse in my graph in Chart.js. When the screen is small it is displayed and when I go back to normal size it is displayed more.

here is my code:

```
if ((window.screen.width > 375) && (window.screen.height > 568)) {
    $scope.billing_options = {
        //responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: true
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                //axe des y
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMax: 0.07,
                    //Create % notation labels
                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        return Math.round((value) * 100) + " %";
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    if (data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label == 'Avenant') {
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + ((factudata[tooltipItem.index].salesVariation)) + " %";
                    } else
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + ((data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index])) + " %";
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question and explain what you mean by "displayed more"?

Comment: i'm sorry for my poor english, i mean that i can not display it i think it is a problem of size of my  canvas